# Miktex not working?

Tags: miktex

I am on Windows 10 and I recently installed MikTex. Every time I look for updates it says error Connecting to the server (500) and when I open their page ([www.miktex.org](http://www.miktex.org)) it says An error occurred while processing your request.

Any help with this?

Comment: See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1298?fbclid=IwAR1mk7D4uxxrAIWuCEKhHLr3GkG9rf3TY23d7_MILL7X8ObAP8ropKKoTfQ

Comment: Open the MikTeX management console and go to the `setting` tab. Click on `change`  to the right of the `Packages are retrieved from` line. A new window opens `Source package` click below on `next` and choose another server.

Comment: Doesn't work. A connection to api2.miktex.org could not be established.

More info: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-couldnt-connect